# How to print both managed and un-managed call stack for the Java dump?

Tags: java, debugging, windbg, dump

In .Net we can use the [!DumpStack](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2009/07/24/managed-debugging-with-windbg-call-stacks-part-1/) to print both managed and un-managed code methods in the call stack from the dump, may I know if there is a equivalent in Java which can also print both managed and un-managed call stack?

Comment: There is only "managed" code in Java. And platform-dependent native code. Not sure what you are talking about here.

Comment: I mean the managed is Java code and un-managed code JVM code, like in .Net we can both see the C# code and CLR  code in the thread call stack.

Comment: Still not clear what you are looking for. JVM internal code is not the same as unmanaged code in .Net. Let's approach it from a different angle: what problem do you have that you want to solve with this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? I don't know for sure about C# but in Java the JVM stack doesn't matter to you unless you're using the JNI (i.e. calling into native code) in which case you can get the stack from the native side.

Comment: I want to see the threads call stack for the JVM((the GC ,finalizer and any other threads of the GC) , as sometimes we need to know what JVM is doing from the JVM threads to troubleshooting some issues happens caused by the JVM itself , for example if the JVM is doing the GC when the performance issue happens or similar issues.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt: there's "managed" code (IL) which gets compiled to native code and there's the Java runtime, also in native code. It is very interesting to look at all three. Sometimes there are bugs in the runtime which you can only figure out when looking at native code. But at the same time you want to know whether you reached the correct point in "managed" code. And IMHO JVM code is unmanaged code. What else should it be? It must use x86 code to run on a x86 PC. The Java EXE must be an EXE that can be run by Windows. That's all native stuff. That early time you can't do it the managed way.

Comment: @joel_s: "JVM stack doesn't matter" - it may be very interesting to learn how the JVM does things, even when you don't use JNI. How do you find bugs in the JVM if not looking at its native code?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd like to comment that the question seems just fine to me, and I find closing your previous question and some of the comments appalling, demonstrating yet again much of what is wrong with SO.

If asking these **questions** about .NET is fine so is **asking** them about Java, even if the **answer** turns out to be "you can't".

(And I'll join in and nitpick for a moment: "Managed" is the Microsoft term for code running under the CLR. You wanted to ask something like "how can I get a usable stack trace in WinDbg containing both the JVM native code and the JITted Java code running in it?")

And now to your question:

---

### Intro

Unfortunately I am not aware of a tool or a plugin for WinDbg that does that, but I think there's a way you can make one yourself. (I thought I might get to it, but I can't find the time, so I thought I'd at least give you the information. Since you asked the question twice, I guess it might be important enough so you'll bother to take the necessary steps.)

Solving your problems can be split into 2 parts:

1. Getting names corresponding to addresses for the JITted code ("Generating symbols").
2. Consuming the generated symbols in WinDbg.

I'll discuss them in order and finish with a few caveats.

### Generating symbols

Brendan Gregg had [basically the same problem with profiling Java code](http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html#Java). He needed function names for the JITted code. The solution, in his own words:

> One approach to solve the above two problems involves:
>
> 1. A JVMTI agent, [perf-map-agent](https://github.com/jrudolph/perf-map-agent), which can provide a Java symbol table for perf to read (/tmp/perf-PID.map).
> 2. Patching JDK hotspot to reintroduce the frame pointer register, which allows full stack walking.

JVMTI stands for Java Virtual Machine Tool Interface. A JVMTI agent is basically a plugin for the JVM that implements callbacks for JVM events that interest him. It can be dynamically loaded or linked into the JVM binary (if you were making a custom build of the JVM).

In the case of perf-map-agent, the plugin asks to know about all the JITted methods and some other dynamically generated pieces of code. It gets their names, addresses and sizes. It then spits out this information to a file that is later used By Linux perf.

You should fork it, change any Linux-specific stuff there's in it (I haven't noticed anything, but maybe there's something hiding) and build it as a DLL in Windows for the Windows version of HotSpot.

You should also change the functions that generate the output file (in `src/c/perf-map-file.c`) to output the info in a format you can make WinDbg to consume, which bring us to the second part.

### Consuming symbols in WinDbg

There are a few ways I can think of to make WinDbg consume symbols generated by that JVMTI agent, and you can probably think for more. I'll mentiond a few that come to mind:

1. Generate a MAP file and convert it to something WinDbg will load.

   - Perhaps convert it to a DBG file with [map2dbg](https://github.com/andremussche/map2dbg).
   - Perhaps even try to make a PDB out of it using [cv2pdb](https://github.com/rainers/cv2pdb).
2. Generate a PDB yourself, perhaps using the information from Microsoft releases on GitHub in the [microsoft-pdb](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-pdb) project.
3. Load symbols into WinDbg using a WinDbg extensions that calls [AddSyntheticSymbol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537943(v=vs.85).aspx).
   You have a code that does that [here](https://gist.github.com/ikonst/ebae548dac7934dc0bdf) (written by blabb, who's active here in SO on the windbg tag). There used to a binary of that code on www.woodmann.com, but that site isn't working for me now (and hasn't been for quite some time). There seems to be a binary [here](https://github.com/siberas/IDA2Sym).

Option 3 seems the simplest to me (and works best from my experience) but you can do whatever you want.

### Caveats

#### RBP chain

You may remember that in Brendan Gregg's quote there was something about patching HotSpot to keep an RBP-chain. Maybe the Windows implementation of HotSpot dynamicaly creates the unwind info WinDbg uses on x64 to walk stacks. Maybe it doesn't. I don't know.

In any case, you don't need to patch the JVM if you're using a relatively recent version. This feature is available as of JDK 8u60 build 19 with the `-XX:+PreserveFramePointer` flag.

#### Freezing the JVM

SOS knows how to parse the CLR data structures in memory. It doesn't need assistance from the CLR itself, I think. That's why you always need the exact SOS version for the CLR used to create a dump, for example.

The JVMTI plugin, in contrast to, is loaded **into** the JVM. Once you break into the debugger, the agent can't do anything, assuming it's even loaded.

perf-map-agent is loaded by a small Java program (`src/java/AttachOnce.java` in he repo), gets the information about the currently JITted function and that's it. You can either do the same, and run the agent before you break, or have the agent working all the time and continuously output information about JITted methods as they come (if you're doing post-mortem debugging for example and the Java process is [mostly dead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey75r.jpg)). In that case you'll have to make some more change to the perf-map-agent code.

#### Passing arguments to embedded JVMs

In case you're debugging an application with an embedded JVM (like Eclipse etc.; where you *don't* run java.exe *args*), you may want to use the [`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html) environment variable which allows you to pass arguments such as the aforementioned `-XX:+PreserveFramePointer` or `-agentlib`/`-agentpath` to load a JVMTI agent from the start instead of attaching to a running JVM like pref-map-agent does.

### Closing words

Sorry I couldn't give you a working tool that does that, but if you really need that it seems pretty doable. Unless WinDbg will be unable to stackwalk completely without the unwind info I don't think there should be any special problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use `jstack.exe`. It's pretty straight forward.

```
C:\Users\conio\Desktop\code\JNA2>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\jstack.exe" -?
Usage:
    jstack [-l] <pid>
        (to connect to running process)
    jstack -F [-m] [-l] <pid>
        (to connect to a hung process)
    jstack [-m] [-l] <executable> <core>
        (to connect to a core file)
    jstack [-m] [-l] [server_id@]<remote server IP or hostname>
        (to connect to a remote debug server)

Options:
    -F  to force a thread dump. Use when jstack <pid> does not respond (process is hung)
    -m  to print both java and native frames (mixed mode)
    -l  long listing. Prints additional information about locks
    -h or -help to print this help message
```

You want to use `-m` to get both the Java stack and the native stack.
If you want to get the stack from a process that crashed but has got a post-mortem debugger attached to it you should use the `-F` flag.

For example, I've got the following code that uses [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna):

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;

import com.sun.jna.Pointer;

public class Foo
{
public interface CLibrary extends Library {
        CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary)Native.loadLibrary("msvcrt", CLibrary.class);

        void printf(String format, Object... args);
        Pointer malloc(int size);
        Pointer memset(Pointer dest, int ch, int count);
        void free(Pointer ptr);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {    
        CLibrary.INSTANCE.printf("Hello, World\n");

        Pointer buf = CLibrary.INSTANCE.malloc(2);
        CLibrary.INSTANCE.memset(buf, 0, 0x20);
        CLibrary.INSTANCE.free(buf);

        CLibrary.INSTANCE.printf("Goodbye, Cruel World\n");
    }
}
```

When I build and execute this code, it crashes and WinDbg attaches to it (as it's set to be my post-mortem debugger).

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.14321.1024 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

*** wait with pending attach
<<<snip>>>
(1f0.14d0): Unknown exception - code c0000374 (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=011eea00 ebx=77b5c908 ecx=00000001 edx=77b5c8d0 esi=00000002 edi=01251240
eip=77b29841 esp=011ee9dc ebp=011eea6c iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+0x89:
77b29841 eb33            jmp     ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+0xbe (77b29876)
0:003> !error c0000374
Error code: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000374 (3221226356) - A heap has been corrupted.
0:003> k
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 011eea6c 77b2cfe2 ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+0x89
01 011eea78 77b2b763 ntdll!RtlpReportHeapFailure+0x32
02 011eea88 77ad16cf ntdll!RtlpHeapHandleError+0x1c
03 011eeab8 77ae278b ntdll!RtlpLogHeapFailure+0x9f
04 011eebc8 77a978aa ntdll!RtlpFreeHeap+0x4aa1b
05 011eebf4 749d77c5 ntdll!RtlFreeHeap+0xba
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\Users\conio\AppData\Local\Temp\jna-71761103\jna991038711348528033.dll
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Users\conio\AppData\Local\Temp\jna-71761103\jna991038711348528033.dll - 
06 011eec40 6e562670 msvcrt!free+0x65
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
07 011eec4c 6e55d8e2 jna991038711348528033!Java_com_sun_jna_Native_setDetachState+0x7020
08 011eec88 6e553c74 jna991038711348528033!Java_com_sun_jna_Native_setDetachState+0x2292
09 011ef580 6e5548c4 jna991038711348528033!Java_com_sun_jna_Native_invokePointer+0xca4
0a 011ef5a8 02c4d3b3 jna991038711348528033!Java_com_sun_jna_Native_invokeVoid+0x24
0b 011ef5ec 02c44854 0x2c4d3b3
0c 011ef62c 02c447b4 0x2c44854
0d 011ef678 02c447b4 0x2c447b4
0e 011ef784 02c40697 0x2c447b4
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\client\jvm.dll - 
0f 011ef794 6e74a1b2 0x2c40697
10 011ef838 6e8104fe jvm!JVM_GetThreadStateNames+0x4cc82
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\java.exe
11 011ef9bc 0083229e jvm!JVM_FindSignal+0x63b3e
12 011ef9d4 02b31310 java+0x229e
13 011ef9d8 02b31310 0x2b31310
14 011efa08 0083aeaf 0x2b31310
15 011efa40 0083af39 java+0xaeaf
16 011efa4c 751f62c4 java+0xaf39
17 011efa60 77ab0609 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
18 011efaa8 77ab05d4 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
19 011efab8 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
0:003> |
.  0    id: 1f0 attach  name: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\java.exe
0:003> ? 0x1f0
Evaluate expression: 496 = 000001f0
0:003> .dump /ma C:\Users\conio\Desktop\code\JNA2\Foo.dmp
Creating C:\Users\conio\Desktop\code\JNA2\Foo.dmp - mini user dump
Dump successfully written
```

And executing `jstack`:

```
C:\Users\conio\Desktop\code\JNA2>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\jstack.exe" -F -m 496
Attaching to process ID 496, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Client compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.102-b14
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

----------------- 0 -----------------
<<<snip>>>
----------------- 3 -----------------
0x77b29841      ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey + 0x4e1
0x77b2cfe2      ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey + 0x3c82
0x77ad16cf      ntdll!wcstok_s + 0x5baf
0x77ae278b      ntdll!LdrSetAppCompatDllRedirectionCallback + 0xff2b
0x77a978aa      ntdll!RtlFreeHeap + 0xba
0x749d77c5      msvcrt!free + 0x65
0x6e562670      jna991038711348528033!_Java_com_sun_jna_Native_setDetachState@20 + 0x7020
0x6e55d8e2      jna991038711348528033!_Java_com_sun_jna_Native_setDetachState@20 + 0x2292
0x6e553c74      jna991038711348528033!_Java_com_sun_jna_Native_invokePointer@24 + 0xca4
0x6e5548c4      jna991038711348528033!_Java_com_sun_jna_Native_invokeVoid@24 + 0x24
0x02c4d3b3      * com.sun.jna.Native.invokeVoid(long, int, java.lang.Object[]) bci:0 (Interpreted frame)
0x02c44854      * com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(java.lang.Object[], java.lang.Class, boolean) bci:29 line:374 (Interpreted frame)
0x02c447b4      * com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Class[], java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[], java.util.Map) bci:249 line:323 (Interpreted frame)
0x02c447b4      * com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object[]) bci:348 line:236 (Interpreted frame)
0x02c447e9      * com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.free(com.sun.jna.Pointer) bci:16 (Interpreted frame)
0x02c44889      * Foo.main(java.lang.String[]) bci:41 line:25 (Interpreted frame)
0x02c40697      <StubRoutines>
0x6e74a6e5      jvm!JVM_GetThreadStateNames + 0x4d1b5
0x6e8104fe      jvm!_JVM_FindSignal@4 + 0x63b3e
0x6e74a77e      jvm!JVM_GetThreadStateNames + 0x4d24e
0x6e6cc337      jvm!JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs + 0x6f27
0x6e6d48cf      jvm!JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs + 0xf4bf
0x0083229e      java + 0x229e
0x0083aeaf      java + 0xaeaf
0x0083af39      java + 0xaf39
0x751f62c4      KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x24
0x77ab0609      ntdll!RtlSubscribeWnfStateChangeNotification + 0x439
0x77ab05d4      ntdll!RtlSubscribeWnfStateChangeNotification + 0x404
----------------- 4 -----------------
<<<snip>>>
```

The symbols above `ntdll!RtlFreeHeap` are a little messed up, but it works.

To use it with a dump file you have to pass it the correct `java.exe` binary, in case you have several version or if you're analyzing it on a different machine than the one on which the dump was generated (similarily to the ay you need the version of `SOS.dll` to macth exactly the .NEt Framework version that was used for dump).

```
C:\Users\conio\Desktop\code\JNA2>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\jstack.exe" -m "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\java.exe" Foo.dmp
Attaching to core Foo.dmp from executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\java.exe, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Client compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.102-b14
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

<<<snip - same output as above>>
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, I would check it more detail later.

Comment: @Jason: Did you get a chance to try it? Did it help you? If so, I'd appreciate you accepting the answer. If this didn't work for you, can you describe what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing two things which cannot be compared.

On one hand side you refer to `!DumpStack` which is a plugin for a debugger. A debugger is written for a specific OS, in this case it's WinDbg for Windows. Of course a debugger for Windows knows how to read a native call stack.

On the other hand side you want to get that information from the JVM. JVM is short for Java virtual machine. If you have worked with virtual machines like VMWare, you know that a VM runs a different "OS". And the name of the OS is Java in this case.

If you consider a Linux VM running on a Windows host, and you use a Linux debugger (GDB) in the VM, will it show the Windows call stack? No, it won't - at least when the VM is designed properly.

Mapping that to the JVM, you should not be able to see the native call stack from inside a Java program, because it runs in a VM.

So, why can `!DumpStack` do it then? Because that's the other way round: when you run a debugger on the Windows host, you can see the call stack of the Linux VM. Same for `!DumpStack`: you're running it from outside the .NET VM and it was designed to interpret the contents of the .NET VM.

So, basically what you want is WinDbg which can read the native side plus a plugin for WinDbg that can interpret the contents of the Java VM (JVM). That again is exactly [the question you have asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584609/is-it-possible-to-do-merged-vm-native-debugging-like-nets-sos-with-java-co), which was considered off-topic, and let me cite my comment from there:

> And unfortunately, no, AFAIK there's no such tool.

I'm ~7 years in the WinDbg business and I found plenty of plugins for various purposes but there's no plugin for showing the Java call stack. I'd love to see one, because I had more than one use case for it.

Comment: Thank for your response, also it is unbelievable why it was considered off-topic.